# How does EGT work?

Tags: engine, temperature, egt

I am making a report and how does EGT of an aircraft, either turbo or piston engine, work? Can you please give me the procedures... Like where it starts and being transferred to where and stuff. Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-does-the-mixture-of-an-engine-affect-the-engines-operation in addition to any answers you might get here.

Comment: @instcpat Are you asking about piston engines or gas turbine ones? I'm not sure about EGT in piston engines.

Comment: @aeroalias I mean for both pls :)

Comment: This is now the second time you have edited this question and completely changed the question. I'm also not sure what the current version is asking.

Answer (score 1):

From all the NASA reports I could find they mostly use [Thermocouples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple). They also use [RTDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_thermometer) which sometimes are called *PT100*. I am not sure if termistors are used.
There is research on optical measurement, but right now I would say that *Thermocouples* and *RTDs* are the common way to measure EGT.

[image]
[http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19800014827.pdf)
[http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/sensors/](http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/sensors/PhySen/docs/AIAA3923_JPC2014.pdf)